# Test trigger before insert

Tags: trigger, unit-test, before-trigger

I'm trying to test a test a trigger that adds an error if the field Active__c is set to true on CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c (son of CreditInfo_Fields__c) and the field Used__c is updated to false. I'm not sure how to create the test data.

This is the trigger:

```
trigger UsedTrigger on CreditInfo_Fields__c (before update) {
    List<CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c> listCred = new List<CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c>();

    listCred = [SELECT Id ,Active__c FROM CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c WHERE CreditInfo_Fields__c IN : trigger.new];
    Set<ID> ids = trigger.newMap.keySet();

    if(trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Id newId : ids){
            if(trigger.newMap.get(newId).Used__c != trigger.oldMap.get(newId).Used__c && trigger.newMap.get(newId).Used__c==false   ){
                for(CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c cred : listcred){
                    if(cred.Active__c == true){
                        trigger.newmap.get(newId).addError('The Credit Info Field is Active on a Rule!');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you will need to consider the relationship between the parent and child records. `CreditInfo_Fields__c` being the parent, `CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c` being the child. We can now insert these objects into the database and not worry about the trigger running, as it is only on an `update` context, for now.

```
CreditInfo_Fields__c creditInfo = new CreditInfo_Fields__c(
    Used__c = true
);

CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c creditInfoEval = new CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c(
    CreditInfo_Fields__c = creditInfo.id,
    Active__c = true
);
```

Once you have the relationship created, you can go ahead and modify the `CreditInfo_Fields__c` field, `Active__c`. Before you cause the trigger to run with an update on the object, think about how you might [report an exception](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_trycatch_example.htm).

```
creditInfo.Used__c = false;

try{
    update creditInfo;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Boolean expectedExceptionThrown =  ex.getMessage().contains('The Credit Info Field is Active on a Rule!') ? true : false;
    System.assertEquals(expectedExceptionThrown, true);    
}
```

By simply reporting the exception is not a good enough test case. We use the [System.assert()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm) methods to confirm our understanding of the logic.

Consider looking into the following Trailhead modules:

1. [Apex Testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing)
2. [Apex Basics & Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_database)
3. [Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_triggers)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have now 66% code coverage!

Comment: @I.Simoes. Ahhh, code coverage. Quality unit testing will give you the coverage you need, focus on the test cases, not the coverage. Think about the happy & unhappy code paths with the above example I have given you.

Comment: This exception testing paradigm is ill advised. If no exception is thrown at all, your recommended test will pass.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create the records for objects, CreditInfo_Fields__c and CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c.

```
CreditInfo_Fields__c infoFields = new CreditInfo_Fields__c();
infoFields.Active__c = true;
infoFields.<OtherFields> = <valueforField>;

insert infoFields;

CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c evalRules = new CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c();
evalRules.Active = true;
evalRules.<OtherFields> = <valueforField>;

insert evalRules;
```

After this you need to update the infoFields record and your trigger should be fired.

```
Test.startTest();
update infoFields;
Test.stopTest();
```

You can a few debug statements in your trigger to trace the flow and set the right values of the fields.